How does one run Capture ONE on UBUNTU?
I saw that UBUNTU has a download to be able to run Capture One.
Can you please confirm the location for that download?

If you're talking about Capture One Photo Editing software, it appears that it's only available for Windows and macOS. According to a question/answer on their website, it states:

QUESTION
Do you have Capture One that can run on Linux?
ANSWER
We continually strive to make Capture One accessible on the newest
hardware and operating systems, and we are aware of how important this
is for many of our users, however, Capture One software is currently
only compatible with macOS and Windows.

This question is about 3 years old, so perhaps it's outdated. In that case, I would reach out to them directly and ask.
Now with that said, Capture One doesn't offer direct download links. You have to create an account first, and then you'll be able to access download links. In my case, since I have an account, I can only see Windows and macOS download links. Thus, it doesn't look like Capture One is available for Ubuntu or any Linux distribution.


Therefore, to be able to run Capture One on an Ubuntu system, the two options I see are installing with WINE or within a Windows VM using something like VirtualBox. I haven't tested installing in either situtation, since I have a dedicated Windows computer for Photoshop/Capture One.
With WINE, this AskUbuntu question will provide some help: How can I install Windows software or games?
